# Mesh from point clouds in Meshlab

Tags: 3d, mesh, point-clouds, meshlab

I need to reconstruct a surface mesh of a terrain from a dense point cloud.

Is it possible to generate polygonal meshes from point clouds in [Meshlab](http://www.meshlab.net/)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can!. The process of generating a mesh from a point cloud is called surface reconstruction.

There are several surface reconstruction methods avaliable in meshlab.

Go to `Filters` -> `Remeshing, simplification and Reconstruction`

There you can select one of the many choices avaliable. To guide you a little:

- [Delanuay Triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) is one of the simplest one and might fit your needs if your surface is not complex.
- [Surface Reconstruction: Screened Poisson](http://hhoppe.com/proj/screenedpoisson/) is state of the art and it's intended for reconstructing complex surfaces. You might need to tweek some parameters on the pop-up dialog in order to obtain the result you want.