# Surface mesh from point cloud in Meshlab

Tags: 3d, mesh, point-clouds, meshlab

I have a point cloud of a terrain, and want to generate a surface mesh.  Is this possible to do in Meshlab?

The point cloud is an xyz file that I generated from a raster file of a Digital Elevation Model.  Each point in the point cloud is on an evenly spaced grid in the x and y axis, and at the desired elevation in the z-axis.  There are around 1 million points.

I can open the xyz file in Meshlab and it looks correct, but I haven't figured out how to generate the surface mesh.

This question is similar or identical to [Mesh from point clouds in Mehlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43774506/mesh-from-point-clouds-in-mehlab).  However, the answer given to this question doesn't work for me.

Comment: This workflow seems to mostly accomplish this, although it doesn't appear to exactly preserve the resolution of the original point cloud.  For this application, I really just want to connect the dots.  Any more suggestions would be great: <br>Filters: Normals, curvatures, and orientation: Compute normals for point sets; <br>Filters: Point set: Marching cubes

Comment: Please provide an example. It sounds like your points just need a 2D triangulation (view from top), not a 3D surface reconstruction

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Remeshing->Surface Reconstruction: Ball Pivoting.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21705562)

Comment: @miken32 I've had a few of these copy and paste messages when it comes to review. This answer will probably help the asker, more than having no response at all would. There is no request for clarification from the user and it is unclear if you have any familiarity with meshlab at all.

Answer (score 0):

to get good results with Screened Poisson or other methods.
First, calculate the normals then use one of the following methods
from filter -> Remeshing, simplification and Reconstruction-> 1-Screened Poisson
2-Ball pivoting
3-alpha complex
4-marching cube

if you used Screened Poisson the faces may be longer than the actual mesh so you can remove them by
filter -> selection -> Select Faces with edges longer than...
then select and apply the edge threshold

hope this answers your question

Best,
MD